# how to print longest common subsequence?

Tags: c++, algorithm

i am learning about lcs and implemented it..but can't find the way to print the longest common subsequence..how to print it??

my lcs code

```cpp
#include<iostream>
#include<algorithm>
#include<cstring>
#include<cstdio>
using namespace std;
int dp[1005][1005];
char a[1005],b[1005];

int lcs(int x,int y)
{
   if(x==strlen(a)||y==strlen(b))
     return 0;
   if(dp[x][y]!=-1)
      return dp[x][y];
   else if(a[x]==b[y])
      dp[x][y]=1+lcs(x+1,y+1);
   else
     dp[x][y]=max(lcs(x+1,y),lcs(x,y+1));
   return dp[x][y];
}
int main()
{
   while(gets(a)&&gets(b))
   {
      memset(dp,-1,sizeof(dp));
      int ret=lcs(0,0);
      printf("%d\n",ret);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Typical approach with dp when you want to recover the optimal solution - add a second array of exactly the same size as the one where you memoize and store in it the 'path' you decided to take. In this case by the 'path' you decided to take I mean the branch leading to the optimal solution.

Looking at the way you implement LCS you have three options for `lcs(x, y)`:

- Its optimal result is achieved when you do `1+lcs(x+1,y+1);` i.e. you include element `x` from `a` and element `y` from b.
- You don't use element `x` from `a`. This happens if you get `dp[x][y]=max(lcs(x+1,y),lcs(x,y+1));` and in fact `lcs(x+1, y)` is the greater of the two values.
- You don't use element `y` from `b`. This happens if you get `dp[x][y]=max(lcs(x+1,y),lcs(x,y+1));` and in fact `lcs(x, y+1)` is the greater of the two values.

The two lowest bullets mean you will have to split this max statement to two ifs.

Now store which of the three choices you choose for each pair `(x,y)` and reconstructing the optimal solution should be pretty straight forward.

Comment: You can also just use the DP array itself to reconstruct the solution by checking at every point which one of the three choices is the max, which saves you space but might be a tiny bit slower (probably unnoticable compared to cache miss costs)

Comment: I deliberately explained the general approach that works for any dp. In this case recovering from the dp array is not very hard but many times it is too complicated. The approach I describe always works.

Comment: @NiklasB. I did not get upset at all, simply giving my argumentation. I think your comment is valuable both for the OP and for the future reader.

Comment: I removed my comment :)

Answer (score 0):

```
void traceback(int i, int j){

 if(i == 0|| j == 0)return;

 if(a[i-1] == b[j-1]) {
 traceback(i-1, j-1);
 cout << a[i-1];
 }
else if( dp[ i ][ j ] > max(dp[ i-1][ j ],dp[ i ][ j-i ] );
traceback(i,j-1);
}
```

This will print sequence in reverse order so correct order can be achieved using array...

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score -1):

i have just used this and it worked for me..

```
void traceback(int i, int j){

 if(i == 0|| j == 0)return;

 if(a[i-1] == b[j-1]) {
 traceback(i-1, j-1);
 cout << a[i-1];
 }
 else if(dp[i-1][j] > dp[i][j-1])
 traceback(i-1, j);
 else traceback(i, j-1);
}
```